# Do all the open sets in real space have measure nonzero?

Tags: measure-theory

$\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, A is a null set (ie $\mu(A)=0$).

If $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash A$ is closed, does it imply $A=\emptyset$?

What happens in general? Different measure in real space? or different space?

Comment: Hint: Every nonempty open set contains an open ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Lebesgue measure, every nonempty open set has positive measure. This was pointed out by Slade in a comment, and answered before: [Are there open sets of measure zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737669/)

For general measures, anything can happen. For example, take Dirac measure (point mass) at a point $x_0$; then any open set not containing $x_0$ has zero measure.